# replace utilizando expressões regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou executando um replace com expressões regulares para formatar uma string, como por exemplo, o CPF:

```
var cpf = '99999999999';
cpfFormatado = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, '$1.$2.$3-$+');
console.log(cpfFormatado); // 999.999.999-99
```

Estou tentando reduzir a expressão regular, no entanto não estou conseguindo encontrar a forma correta para utilizar os grupos na string de substituição:

```
var cpf = '99999999999';
cpfFormatado = cpf.replace(/(\d{3}){3}(\d{2})/, '$1.$2.$3-$+');
console.log(cpfFormatado); // 999.99.$3-99
```

Como eu poderia chegar ao mesmo resultado do primeiro código utilizando a expressão regular do segundo?

Comment: seria isto que esta procurando? `(\d{3})(\1)(\1)(\d{2})`

Comment: Sua primeira saída está errada, o último grupo é **$4**.

Comment: @LuisHenrique Não está errada. `$+` pega o último grupo encontrado, ou seja, irá retornar o grupo `(\d{2})`. Utilizar `$4` daria o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Sua expressão funcionou perfeitamente. Poderia escrever uma resposta explicando como funciona?

Comment: Estranho que rodei aqui no console e não funcionou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso. Quando você reduz `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})` para isso `(\d{3}){3}`, você está eliminando dois grupos de captura, sendo que o primeiro grupo de captura será sobrescrito duas vezes, fazendo com que ele fique com o valor da última captura.

```
var cpf = '12345678901';
cpfFormatado = cpf.replace(/(\d{3}){3}(\d{2})/, '$1.$2.$3-$+');
console.log(cpfFormatado); // 789.01.$3-$+
```

Para saber o que está disponível para ser usado, basta utilizar uma função de replacement, e ver o que ela recebe como argumentos:

```
var cpf = '12345678901';
cpfFormatado = cpf.replace(/(\d{3}){3}(\d{2})/, function() {
    debugger; // ao parar aqui vamos ver o que tem dentro de arguments
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
});
```

Os argumentos passados para a função no exemplo acima são:

```
["12345678901", "789", "01", 0, "12345678901"]
```

Veja como o "789" aparece no grupo 1.

Comment: Boa observação, não havia notado que o grupo estava sendo sobrescrito.

Comment: Apesar da semântica do parse ser a mesma, quando você necessita usar os valores dos grupos, as vezes é necessário decompor a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Como solicitado:

```
(\d{3})(\1)(\1)(\d{2})
```

#### Composição

```
(\d{3})   -  grupo nº 1
(\1)      -  grupo nº 2, que utiliza a mesma expressão do grupo 1
(\1)      -  grupo nº 3, que utiliza a mesma expressão do grupo 1
(\d{2})   -  grupo nº 4
```

#### Explicação

Você pode fazer a utilização de expressões já feitas, fazendo delas um grupo e chamando pelos atalhos `\1-\9`, lembrando que só se pode tem um máximo de 9 atalhos `\9`.

Em resumo `(\d{3})` é a expressão agrupada que possui atalho `\1`

Comment: Isso não irá capturar o CPF "12345678901"

Comment: `\1` até `\9` é utilizado para se remeter a uma captura anterior, e não a uma expressão anterior.

Comment: `\1` não é um atalho pra mesma expressão do grupo de captura 1, ele é um *backreference* pro que foi capturado no grupo 1. Sua regex só vai aceitar CPFs cujos 3 grupos de 3 dígitos sejam iguais.

Comment: De fato, desculpe o erro.